# Express.js StaticPath problem | CSS not being applied on one Page while HBS not getting loaded on other Page

Tags: node.js, express, static, handlebars.js

I'm using Express.js and static path is set.

**What i'm trying to do:**

1. Serve 2 `.hbs` files --> (`index.hbs` & `about.hbs`)
2. Load a Partial in both of them (header)
3. Apply a little CSS file

**What's Happening:**

1. CSS is loaded on `index.hbs` while partial is not loaded on it.
2. CSS is NOT loaded on `about.hbs` while partial is being loaded.
3. Receiving this error on `about.hbs` console window: `Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/public/css/homePageStyles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

**Setting Static Path:**

```
const staticPath = path.join(__dirname, "../public")
app.use(express.static(staticPath))
```

**Folder Structure:**

[image]

**Full Source Code Link:**
https://github.com/jeeemmyy/7.-Partials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue has to do with how you are registering your static assets path with [Express](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html#serving-static-files-in-express).

Your registration looks like this:

```
const staticPath = path.join(__dirname, "../public")
app.use(express.static(staticPath))
```

This is telling Express to look in the "../public" folder on the server for a static file whose path *relative to the ../public folder* matches that of the request.

For example, a request for "localhost:3000/css/homePageStyle.css" would match a file on the server at "../public/css/homePageStyle.css".

But note that "public" is *not* included in the HTTP request path because it is the *root* folder in which Express looks for static files.

To fix your CSS references in your templates, you would need to do either:

1. Remove "public" from the style link href in your templates: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/css/homePageStyles.css">` becomes `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/homePageStyles.css">`.
2. Specify "/public" as a virtual path prefix when registering your static assets path with Express: `app.use("/public", express.static(staticPath))`.

Next, the reason your homepage is not including your header partial is because your index.hbs file is not even getting processed! You have an "index.html" file in your "public" folder. When your HTTP request is to localhost:3000/, Express looks in the server's public folder and finds a match with index.html and so returns that without even executing the GET handler for "/". You need to remove that "index.html" file, as you are not intending to serve it.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, this solved my problem. I am really really thankful to you for the detailed explanation of my question. I was stuck on this for 2 days. Lots of love from Pakistan.

Comment: @ZaeemJaved: Shukriya. Koi baat nahi. (I hope I am using those correctly)

Comment: Hahaha. Omg. Yes you're using them 100% correctly.