# Problem accessing css from handlebars (express API)

Tags: javascript, css, api, express, handlebars.js

So i've run into a problem, where i simply can't get the css to have any effect on my hbs code.

My service has a structure like this:

- Service

  - Controllers
  - Models
  - public

    - css

      - styles.css
  - Routers
  - Views

    - index.hbs
  - app.js
  - package.json
  - Procfile
  - node_modules
  - package-lock.json

Now, I want my index.hbs file to use the stylesheet "styles.css" in the public css folder.
therefore i put a reference in index.hbs to it with: 
 link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/styles.css">

also, I put *app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));* in my app.js

When I *ctrl+click* the reference in the hbs (in VSC) it takes me to the right css file, yet it doesn't work when i run the app. Is something wrong with the app routing? i feel like i've tried everything, so appreciate any feedback

- Fred

Comment: The stylesheet will be relative to your application. You also shouldn't need to put the `public` path because that's already assumed to be where everything is coming from. You should just go `/css/styles.css` in your `link`

Comment: oh wow. i feel super dumb right now. thanks a lot - i could've spent hours trying to find advanced solutions. really appreciate it

Comment: Similar questions have been asked before. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66732509/3397771

Answer (score 0):

When you have set "public" folder as static you don't have to define relative path, your link should be as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```