# CSS JS and image file not working after sending message in nodejs using handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

Code Snippet-

```
exports.afterLogin = async (req, res) => {
try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    db.query('Select * FROM patient_login WHERE email= ?', [email], async (error, results) => {
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
        console.log(results);
        if (!results || !(await bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password))) {
            res.status(400).render('patientLogin', {
                message: 'Email or password is incorrect!',
                messageClass:'alert-warning'
            });
        }
```

Image before
[This is the image of the page before entering credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSrcS.png)
Image after
[This is the Image of the page after entering wrong credentials(See logo)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdX4w.png)

This is the error at the console-

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:3050/auth/afterLogin 400 (Bad Request)
```

afterLogin:1

Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:3050/auth/css/index.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
afterLogin:23

GET http://127.0.0.1:3050/auth/images/logo.png 404 (Not Found)
afterLogin:97

GET http://127.0.0.1:3050/auth/javascript/validateLogin.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

page at starting-home/patientLogin
page after entering bad credentials-home/auth/afterlogin

Comment: My guess is it has to do with how you are registering and using your static assets path. See these posts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66732509/3397771 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/61741846/3397771

Comment: Here are my static paths, please have a look.
app.use(express.static('public'))

    app.use('/css',express.static(__dirname + 'public/css'))
    app.use('/javascript',express.static(__dirname + 'public/javascript'))
    app.use('/images',express.static(__dirname + 'public/images'))

Not working,please help

Comment: to begin with, I don't see `/auth` registered as a static path, but you are requesting an image at `/auth/images/logo.png`

Comment: I did it man,found the error. Thanks a lot for showing up!