# Multiple handlebar file is not reading css files

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

The first handlebar file i.e **index.hbs** , It reads css file which is in public folder but **about.hbs** is not able to read it. Please tell me the solution of this.

This is my file.
[image]

Here is my **about.hbs** page

[image]

Comment: Did you check you are correctly importing css file in about.hbs? It may be happening due to you are importing css file from /about/css in about.hbs check your generated html in browser.

Comment: @RahulKrishna yes I copied and pasted index.hbs file to about.hbs. It works in index but not in about page

Comment: Could you check css file path in generated html. It is most probably due to wrong path.

Comment: I did. I changed it many times. I tried giving it relative path then absolute path but nothing works

Comment: Use css like "/css/styles.css". For views in express you can simply write app.set("views", "views"); and for static files app.use(express.static("public")); you don't need full path with express.

Comment: I already tried this :(

Comment: Could you show about.hbs?

Comment: I updated it. Please check

Comment: I tried this app.use(express.static("public")) but doesnt work

Comment: Perhaps this post can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66732509/3397771

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const viewsFilePath = path.join(__dirname,'views')
```

Dont Need To put (../)