# CSS file is not applied to 404 error page when I go to localhost/about/{randomtext} in nodejs

Tags: css, node.js, express, handlebars.js

As you can see from title, my css file does not apply to **localhost/about/{anyrandomtext}** but it applies to **localhost/{anyrandomtext}**

I tried to do this but it doesn't work :

```
app.get('/about/*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('404')
})
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('404')
})
```

I used `app.use('/public', express.static(staticFilePath))` following this [Express.js StaticPath problem | CSS not being applied on one Page while HBS not getting loaded on other Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66724768/express-js-staticpath-problem-css-not-being-applied-on-one-page-while-hbs-not/66732509#66732509) and it worked for all pages. CSS applied on all pages but now I'm having problem with 404 error page.
this is my file structure

[image]

**header.hbs**

```
**<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/styles.css">**
<title>Weather</title>
```

**404.hbs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    {{> header}}
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container error_page">
        <img src="../../public/images/404error.png" alt="">
        <h1>Page could not be Found</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn">Go to Home</button>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my code. Please help

```
const express = require('express')
const hbs = require('hbs')
const path = require('path')
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000
const app = express()

const staticFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '../public')
const viewsFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '../templates/views')
const partialPath = path.join(__dirname, '../templates/partials')

hbs.registerPartials(path.join(partialPath))
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
app.set('views', viewsFilePath)
app.use('/public', express.static(staticFilePath))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index')
})
app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.render('about')
})
app.get('/weather', (req, res) => {
    res.render('weather')
})

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('404')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Successfully connected at port ${port}`);
})
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `app.use(express.static(staticFilePath))` instead of `app.use('public', express.static(staticFilePath))`

Comment: I tried it but then css will not apply to all files and this error will come : Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/public/css/homePageStyles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

Comment: How do you link the css?

Comment: I don't see any `<link>` tag

Comment: It's supposed to be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">`. But if it doesn't work, try removing the `/` in the front, so `href="css/style.css"`

Comment: it worked. I also changed this app.use('public',express.static(staticFilePath)) to app.use(express.static(staticFilePath)). Thank you soo muchhhh