# stylesheet does not work in handlebar template

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I am using handlebars template in express and node. But seems like it cannot apply style in my template
here is my directory:

[image]

my template

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>RYZE Report</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" >
   
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello hi</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and in my app.js, I have this line

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))`

Thank you

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the `.` at the beginning of your css relative path. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66732509/3397771

Comment: I follow the solution in suggested post but it does not solve my problem. I remove  `.` also but still cannot show my style.  here is my repo [link](https://github.com/Amberchen8892/pdf-handerbars). Can you take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have looked at the code and I made a couple of improvements to make this work, instead of compiling the document without any inputs, I have made a css input as the following in the template.hbs:

```
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
  {{css}}
</style>
<title>Hello, world!</title>
```

I have also edited the app.js to read the css along with the html and embed the css into it like so: app.js:

```
const template = fs.readFileSync('template.hbs', 'utf8');
const css = fs.readFileSync('./public/css/style.css', 'utf-8');
const DOC = Handlebars.compile(template);
```

and used the DOC as following:

```
DOC({css})
```

this will inline the css inside of the hbs file, I hope this answers your question

Comment: I want to generate a pdf in express node therefore I use handlerbars template

Comment: @PhuongTran I have cloned your repo and tried to fix the problem, please see the updated answer, hope it solves your problem

Comment: I works ! Thank you. what if I want to add external js file? I do the same thing like you did with css. I add 
`const jsFile = fs.readFileSync('./public/js/index.js', 'utf8')`

DOC as following :
`DOC({ css: css, jsFile: jsFile,})`

in template.hds: 
` <body> <h1 class="text" >Hello </h1><script> {{jsFile}}</script>`

But it doesnt work. Thank you